# Tk on OCaml, How does 'Button.flash' work ?

Tags: user-interface, ocaml, tk-toolkit

I am a new person to OCaml GUI programming.
I would like to know how 'Button.flash' on Tk module works.

Here is my code;

```
open Tk
open Printf


(*
 *   +--------------------------------------------+
 *   |                  Window                    |
 *   +--------------------------------------------+
 *   |                +---------+                 |
 *   |                | BUtton  |                 |
 *   |                +---------+                 |
 *   +--------------------------------------------+
 *) 

let top = openTk() 
let frame = Frame.create top
let label = Label.create frame ~text:"hoge"
let hoge_button = Button.create frame ~text:"hoge"
let f () =  Button.flash hoge_button; Unix.sleep 1 
let fuga_button = Button.create frame ~text:"fuga" ~command:(f);;


let () = 
    pack [coe label; coe fuga_button; coe hoge_button] ~side:`Left;
    pack [coe frame] ~side:`Top;
    mainLoop()
```

I compiled it. And when I pressed fuga button, then hoge button does not flash. I thought that should I update some parameter ? 
But I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: I am running on "macOS".

Comment: I compiled the same code on Linux, and it really makes sense.
So, I concluded that this problem is owing only to the Tk module system on MacOS.

Comment: I'm unsure about the behaviour of the Unix module on a non Unix system. Maybe your problem lies here?

Comment: I do not know what you mentioned by 'Unix System', but I think what you are saying is right. I could not make `Button.flash` work just on MacOS :-(

Comment: As a side note, MacOS is Unix, unlike GNU/Linux that is Unix compatible and is not Unix. And GNU stands for GNU is Not Unix.